# How to change the shape of button from rectangle to Circle in xamarin using xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have a rectangle button in my activity. Should I change to a circle shape. How can I achieve this using the XAML?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this [enter link description here](https://github.com/vincentgury/XFShapeView)
change ShapeType

```
var box = new ShapeView
{
    ShapeType = ShapeType.Box,
    HeightRequest = 75,
    WidthRequest = 75,
    Color = Color.Navy,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    CornerRadius = 5,
    BorderColor = Color.Red,
    BorderWidth = 1f,
    Content = new Label
    {
        Text = "Touch me!",
        FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof (Label)),
        TextColor = Color.White,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
    },
};

var tap = new TapGestureRecognizer
{
    Command = new Command(() => {
        this.DisplayAlert("Touched", "This shape responds to touch!", "Ok");
    })
};

box.GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is only possible in IOS with cornerradius but i don't think this is possible for PCL or other Xamarin solutions with xaml. You probably have to make a custom renderer.